# Create child without parent using EntityFramework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.Net core (1.1) Web API I have two models: Task and Feature. Initially I create one or many Tasks and then I can combine few of them to be a Feature.

For this I have written my models as following:

```
public class User_Task
{
    [Key]
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeatureId")]
    public long FeatureId { get; set; }

    public User_Task()
    {

    }

}
```

and Feature:

```
public class Feature
{
    [Key]
    public long FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string Analyst_comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User_Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public Feature()
    {

    }
}
```

Now the problem is: I am not being able to create a task without first creating a Feature- I tried passing featureId as 0 or null for POST request of Tasks but it fails (for null I get bad request and for 0 it throws exception).

What should I modify in my models or controller or repo class to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your `FeatureId` `nullable`.

```
public class User_Task
{
    [Key]
    public long TaskId { get; set; }
    public string What { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeatureId")]
    public long? FeatureId { get; set; }
}
```

then add and run an migration, EF Core should be able to figure out it's an optional one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thanks! this worked but it threw me exception MySqlException: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' while creating a Feature

Comment: It means the feature (with id 3) already exists. When creating a feature you must **not** set `FeatureId`, i.e. if you do `new Feature { Id = 3 }` and then add it. Instead, you first need to load it and mutate the loaded entity or attach it first, using `dbcontext.Attach(feature)`

Comment: Well in my database there is no feature so far, and as my Swagger API suggests I pass featureId=0 while feature creation, which basically works for task creation. the number 3 is actually referring to taskId! So basically as task with taskId 3 exists it do not let me create a feature that has task with that id which is 3

Comment: Technically 0 is a valid primary key (when its integer or big integer) in mysql, even though AUTO_INCREMENT will always start with 1 (so an created entity will never have 1, unless you add it specifically). Dunno how the provider you use treats that. Maybe related to [this issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/223)